# DataFrame is not concatenating correctly

Tags: string, dataframe, concatenation

I have a file consisting of .csv files of more than 365 days, each labeled by day e.g. 1 Jun 2022, 1 Jun 2021. I want to concat a few selected files: 1 December - 15 March of both 2021 and 2022, so i can average the values via groupby for time and PV output

For background, each csv file has approx 8 columns and 149 rows, so i should get quite a large no. of rows, but its not concatenating right, and I'm not sure how to stop concatenation at 15 march instead of concatenating the whole of march. the result for below code is (148,8)

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import os

valid_suffixes = ('Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar')

excel_dir = '/kaggle/input/pv-updated/PV'

first_file = '/kaggle/input/pv-updated/PV/1 Dec 2022.csv'
dec_15mar= pd.read_csv(first_file)

if filename.endswith(valid_suffixes):
      file_path = pd.read_csv(name)
      dec_15mar = pd.concat([file_path, dec_15mar], ignore_index=True)  # Corrected ignore_index to True

print(dec_15mar.shape)
```